# How to get rsync to synchronize only new blocks for blockchain

Tags: backup, sync, rsync

Every time I run rsync to backup a blockchain, it starts from the beginning and tries to sync the whole thing, every time, even though there may only be a few blocks worth of data that is new. The rsync man page says, "It is famous for its delta-transfer algorithm, which reduces the amount of data sent over the network by sending only the differences between the source files and the existing files in the destination," but I cannot figure out how to get it to only update the new info that has been added to the blockchain. As the chain is very large, it is ridiculous to keep copying the whole thing every day. Can rsync backup only new data, and if so, how can I tell it to do so?

This what I am using:

```
> rsync -avz --exclude-from=/exclude/file -e ssh /from/file server@ip.address:/backup/file
```

Comment: How do you reckon it copies the entire file? Did you measure the amount of data transferred during the process? Try without the `-z ` flag, and see if it actually copies the entire filesize during I/O operation.

Comment: You could compare the i-numbers of some files before and after the transfer (`ls -i`).

Comment: @ Artur Meinild It was taking a really long time, so I ran it manually with the -P flag which shows clearly what is happening. Every time I ran it, it would start from 0 again.

Comment: @Artur Meinild Just tried without the -z option (and -P) and it started from the beginning again. It showed I had half an hour to go for syncing to complete despite the diff is a bit over 1MB. Also the size transferring was Gigs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this article](https://fedoramagazine.org/copying-large-files-with-rsync-and-some-misconceptions/), a combination of the following properties should work for you:

```
--partial --inplace --append
```

In your case that would be:

```
rsync -avz --partial --inplace --append --exclude-from=/exclude/file -e ssh /from/file server@ip.address:/backup/file
```

It also makes sense to me that a blockchain would only need "appended" data, i.e. added blocks.

In addition, `--progress` can be added as well.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need the `--inplace` option.

Normally, *rsync* creates a new file for every transfer and removes the old one when the transfer was successful, so any interrupt will still keep one version of the file intact. With `--inplace` it writes the existing file directly, so an interrupt may leave an inconsistent file behind; that's why it's not the default.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try it when I get back. Does it matter if I point directly to the file itself, or should I point to the containing folder (I only want to update one specific file - the blockchain). I want to get it right because if it starts from the beginning again, I have to wait more than half an hour for it to finish again.

Comment: That really shouldn't matter. Normally, _rsync_ creates a new file for every transfer and removes the old one when the transfer was successful, so any interrupt will still keep one version of the file intact. With `--inplace` it writes the existing file directly, so an interrupt may leave an inconsistent file behind; that's why it's not the default.

Comment: [This article](https://fedoramagazine.org/copying-large-files-with-rsync-and-some-misconceptions/) mentions the following combination of parameters: `--partial --inplace --append --progress`. I think you have to do a little experimentation to find out which are needed in your case.

Comment: @HuHa, it would be good to include that useful explanatory information in the answer itself for future reference. Comments are temporary, and may disappear.

Comment: @vanadium Edited the answer.

Comment: @HuHa tried with -avP flags and --inplace but it is copying the whole thing again....

Comment: Maybe the differences are greater than you think. Try a binary comparison (`cmp`?) to find out.

Comment: @ Artur Meinild The article you linked was very interesting and what I needed was --append finally as --inplace simply copies the whole file from scratch each time which does not help me. Its tricky because -vn gives the same output for --append and --inplace although they do very different things, so I had to do a live testing which was very time consuming. Write your suggestions as an answer and I'll accept it as they led me to my answer.

Comment: @ArturMeinild I see that I put your name with spaces above so maybe you don't get it and I cannot edit it.